# BMO1 2009/10 Question 4 Geometry Problem

Tags: geometry, contest-math, circles

> Two circles, of different radius, with centres at $B$ and $C$, touch
>   externally at $A$. A common tangent, not through $A$, touches the
>   first circle at $D$ and the second at $E$. The line through $A$ which
>   is perpendicular to $DE$ and the perpendicular bisector of $BC$ meet at
>   $F$. Prove that $BC = 2AF$.

[(source)](https://bmos.ukmt.org.uk/home/bmo1-2010.pdf) (British Mathematical Olympiad
)

Thanks in advance for any contributions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Let the radii of the circles be $r_1$ and $r_2$ respectively and let the length $CG$ be $r_2+x$. Since $\triangle CGE\sim\triangle BGD$, $\dfrac{CE}{CG}=\dfrac{BD}{BG}$ or :$$\dfrac{r_2}{r_2+x}=\dfrac{r_1}{r_1+2r_2+x}\implies x=\dfrac{2r_2^2}{r_1-r_2}\implies CG=\dfrac{r_2(r_1+r_2)}{r_1-r_2}$$

Also since $\triangle AHF\sim\triangle CEG$, $\dfrac{AH}{AF}=\dfrac{CE}{CG}$.
 Now use this to calculate the length of $AF$ and compare it with the length of $BC$

Comment: Don't we need the length of AH to calculate the length of AF?

Comment: @MadChickenMan The length of $AH$ is simply $BA-BH$, both of which are known.

Comment: Am I missing something, what is the length of BH?

Comment: $BH=\dfrac{r_1+r_2}{2}$ because $HF$ is the perpendicular bisector of $BC$

Comment: Ah yes, well thank you for all your help. By the way, what software is it you used to construct your diagram, I've seen it before, but I'm not sure of the name of it.

Comment: [Geogebra](http://geogebra.org/).